# Uri.IsWellFormedUriString() returns false for a URL which is correct

Tags: c#, .net, coreclr

I have a C# (.Net Core 1.1) app that needs to check if a URL is valid. I used the Uri.IsWellFormedUriString() which works pretty well but have a doubt about this one below which returns false. It seems to me that the URL is perfectly valid?

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://www.test.com/search/Le+Venezuela+b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficie+d%27importantes+ressources+naturelles+%3A+p%C3%A9trole%2C+gaz%2C+mines", UriKind.Absolute)
```

I used the very same URL with the PHP function below which says the URL is correctly formatted:

```
function filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the problem is that the url is escaped. Try this using [`UnscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string urlencoded= "http://www.test.com/search/Le+Venezuela+b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficie+d%27importantes+ressources+naturelles+%3A+p%C3%A9trole%2C+gaz%2C+mines";
var isWellFormed=Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(
                       Uri.UnescapeDataString(urlencoded), 
                       UriKind.Absolute);
```

**EDIT**

As you are using .net core, maybe you'll need to use [`System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urldecode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [bug in DotNet.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21626) Uri.IsWellFormedUriString() always returns false if the URI contains both a non-ascii character like Å or ตั together with any of the URI Reserved Characters (`! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? # [ ]`) it will fail if that reserved character is percent encoded.

These will pass:

```
"https://example.com/a"
"https://example.com/a*"
"https://example.com/a%2A"
"https://example.com/*"
"https://example.com/%2A"
"https://example.com/%C3%A5*"
"https://example.com/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%B1*"
```

And these will fail:

```
"https://example.com/%C3%A5%2A"
"https://example.com/%E0%B8%95%E0%B8%B1%2A"
```

So effectively, you will either have to strip out those percentage encoded special characters, find a different URI checker, or wait for Microsoft to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `%2C`, which is **unnecessarily** escaped; make it a comma, and it reports true.

Comment: That's not the whole story though: `"http://www.test.com/x%2C"` reports `true` as well. `"http://x.com/%C3%A9x%2C"` is broken, but removing the `%C3`, the `%A9`, the `x` or the `%2C` makes it okay. I'm confused.

Comment: You are right, and @JonSkeet too. So maybe is not a bad idea unescape the url before checking if it is well formed

Comment: @JonSkeet unscaping your second example and escaping it again it gives `http://x.com/%C3%A9x,`, so I think that is what is considered as a correctly escaped uri

Comment: @Pikoh: How are you escaping it? And why do the `%C3%A9` make a difference? I definitely can't see a pattern here at the moment...

Comment: @JonSkeet https://dotnetfiddle.net/EKx5bc. BTW, just removing the `x` does not make it valid

Comment: @Pikoh: Oops, I must have failed when trying the "just x" version. I still don't see why removing `%C3%A9` should make a difference though... It's all very odd.

Comment: [This was reposted on corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19630), where I've independently done some more research. @Flo Next time, when you repost a question somewhere else, you should link to the previous location, so that people don't waste time researching it again.